# pass an arrayList created in the main method to another class

Tags: java

i need your help :)
i have a class Main :

```
public class Main {

   private static ArrayList<Integer> xCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private static ArrayList<Integer> yCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();


 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Adress adress2 = new Adress(6, 8);
     TourManager.addAdress(adress2);
     Adress adress3 = new Adress(3, 4);
     TourManager.addAdress(adress3);
     Adress adress4 = new Adress(9, 12);
     TourManager.addAdress(adress4);
     Adress adress5 = new Adress(12, 16);
     TourManager.addAdress(adress5);

      // Initialize intial solution

     Tour currentSolution = new Tour();

     currentSolution.generateIndividual();
     Tour best = new Tour(currentSolution.getTour());
     System.out.println("Distance From adress (0,0): " + best.getDistance());
     System.out.println("Solution distance : " + best.toString()+ "\n"); 

      // i try to sent x and y Coordinates in my too ArraList xCoords, yCoords list
      // in the oder to be used in the second class to draw line.

         for (int i = 0; i < best.tourSize(); i++) {
              xCoords.add(i, best.getAdress(i).x);
              yCoords.add(i, best.getAdress(i).y);
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < best.tourSize(); i++) {
              System.out.print(yCoords.get(i)+ " - ");
         }

         new Draw(); // new instance

}
```

Hier my second class to draw line :

```
public class Draw extends JPanel {


    //private static ArrayList<Integer> xCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //private static ArrayList<Integer> yCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // how can i recover the tow ArrayList xCoords, yCoords in the order to make a loop for to exract x,y


          public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
          {

             final int offset = 5; 

             super.paintComponent(g);
             g.setColor(new Color(54,34,56));

             for(int i = 1; i <xCoords.size() ; i++)
             {
                 g.fillOval(xCoords.get(i), yCoords.get(i), 8, 8);
                 g.setColor(Color.RED);
                 g.drawLine(xCoords.get(i-1)+offset, yCoords.get(i-1)+ offset, xCoords.get(i)+ offset, yCoords.get(i)+ offset);
             }

          }

    public Draw() {

        final int width = 400; // Breite des Fensters
        final int height = 450; // Hoehe des Fensters
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(width, height);
        f.add(this);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

i tried to instantiate Tour in Draw class, create a Loop for to add x,y coordinates in ArrayList then make another Loop to exract x, y to draw a line but in my tour i have no data and i should recreate Adress (x, y) to have data !

Comment: And unfortunately I have no real clue what exactly your problem and your question is. You see, the question how to pass an arraylist to another object ... is like ... very trivial (by passing it?); but I have really no idea what you are asking. Hint: reduce your question to the absolute minimum. Don't start with your "full example"; take away **anything** that is not part of the problem you are trying to solve. So don't talk about drawing, painting, whatsoever.

Comment: It looks like you are using mutable static fields throughout your application. This is bad design... don't do it :)

Comment: Use a constructor parameter to pass the list.

Comment: it is very simple, i try to recover an ArrayList from main method and recover it on the second class, extract data and used to generate a graph.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass something to another class, just write a Constructor of the Class and add parameters for the things you want to pass.

In your case it would be smth like this:

```
public class Draw extends JPanel { 
...
    public Draw(ArrayList<Integer> xCoords, ArrayList<Integer> yCoords) {
        // your code here. You can access the arraylists by the parameter name yCoords and xCoords
    }
...
}
```

After that you just create an object of the class Draw and pass your arrays.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Krossi, that's really what i expected, but i have a Problem with **paintComponent(Graphics g)** `xCoord.size()` is empty and when i try to make System.out.println(xCoord.size()) outside this method in my constructor for exemple it works !

Comment: i used a constructor parameter to pass the list  but i have something wrong with my paint method. I would really appreciate if anyone could explain (simply) why my Coordinates seems like null. I try to give a separate example so I can get a better understanding) <br/>

Comment: If you use your Code from above, the error is in the constructor call. `new Draw();` It hast to be `new Draw(xCoords, yCoords);` After that your Draw class knows about the xCoords-Arraylist. If you want to use the same Draw-object later, save the instance in a variable. `Draw myDrawVariableName = `.